# Swift Object not mutating

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit

When I go to mutate the "rings" property of the main() object created in the "content view", it does not change. The makeQuery() function doesn't change the rings property of "fitness" created in content view. Why is makeQuery() not changing this property of the fitness object? I have tried pretty much every brute force technique I could think of.

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit


    
    
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello!").padding().onAppear {
            var fitness = main()
            fitness.main()
            print(fitness.rings) 
            //this is always null even though the makeQuery function which should mutate the rings value does nothing when called here.

            }
                    
                    
            }
        }
    
    
    struct fitnessView: View {
        
        @State var rings : HKActivitySummary
        
        var body: some View {
            let red = Int(rings.activeEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: .largeCalorie()))
            let green = Int(rings.appleExerciseTime.doubleValue(for: .minute()))
            //let blue = Int(rings.appleStandHours.doubleValue(for: .hour()))
            VStack {
                Text("\(red)").foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("\(green)").foregroundColor(.green)
                //Text("\(blue)").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    class main {
        
        let healthstore = HKHealthStore()
        
        var rings : HKActivitySummary = HKActivitySummary()
    
        
        
        
        
        func authorizeHealthkit() {
            
            
            let allTypes = Set([HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()])
            
            healthstore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: allTypes) { (chk, error) in if(chk) {
                print("permission granted")
            }
            }
        }
        
        func makeQuery() {
            
            let calendar = NSCalendar.current
            let endDate = Date()
        
            
            guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: endDate) else {
                fatalError("error")
            }
            
            let units: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day, .month, .year, .era]
            
            var startDatecomps = calendar.dateComponents(units, from: startDate)
            startDatecomps.calendar = calendar
            
            var endDatecomps = calendar.dateComponents(units, from: endDate)
            endDatecomps.calendar = calendar
            
            let summariesWithinRange = HKQuery.predicate(forActivitySummariesBetweenStart: startDatecomps, end: endDatecomps)
            
            let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: summariesWithinRange) {
                (sample, results, error) -> Void in
                if let results = results {
                    if let summary = results.first {
                        self.rings = summary
                        // self.rings successfully mutated here when I print it out
                        // but does not result in the actual "fitness" object changing


                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            healthstore.execute(query)
        }
        
        func getRings() -> HKActivitySummary {
            return self.rings
        }
        
        
        func main() {
            self.authorizeHealthkit()
            self.makeQuery()
            print(self.getRings())
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You may want to consider formatting your code (ctrl-i) and adopting standard Swift capitalization practices (types start with capital letters) to make your code easier for others to read.

Comment: Watch meet async await there are quite a few things that need improvement.

Answer (score 1):

HKActivitySummary is a class, so you cannot use @State. Also, you cannot use @StateObject wrapper, because it does not conform to ObservableObject. You have to wrap HKActivitySummary in some envelope, and program a mechanism that will check for changes. More work to do, or choose another approach.

Class names should start with capital, so rename main to Main. main and Main are not good choices for names, as these are used by Swift, rename these.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ContentView`, try modify your code as below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @StateObject var fitness = main() //this part
 var body: some View {
    Text("hello!").padding().onAppear {
        fitness.main() //this part
        print(fitness.rings)
        //this is always null even though the makeQuery function which should mutate the rings value does nothing when called here.
        }        
    }
 }
```

And in your class `main` modify these parts:

```
class main : ObservableObject { //this part
    let healthstore = HKHealthStore()
    @Published var rings : HKActivitySummary = HKActivitySummary() //this part
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I made the exact changed and still getting an empty rings. Gave me this error: "[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates."

Comment: Any time you update rings, you should do so on the main thread. For example, you could wrap the calls in `Task { @MainActor in }`

Comment: the only time it’s updated is in the makeQuery method. “self.rings = summary”. Can you show what I should put there?

Comment: HKActivitySummary is a class, so the @Published wrapper will not publish a value when anything inside the instance changes. This must be manually programmed or another approach selected. You want to be notified when the activity summary changes, but this is not a standard functionality. Very likely you will need to program it. Not a beginner task.